# Find distinct non-zero integers $a,b,c$ for which the number $\overline{a0b0c}$ is divisible by $\overline{abc}$

Tags: elementary-number-theory, divisibility

> Find distinct non-zero integers $a,b,c$ for which the number $\overline{a0b0c}$ is divisible by $\overline{abc}$.

I'm stuck on this question and the only solution I've seen involves programming. I was wondering if there's a methodical way to solve this problem on paper. I was thinking maybe starting by checking $\mod 10$ for each possible value of $c$ but there are too many cases...

Edit: An interesting observation is that both numbers are congruent modulo $9$, $10$.

Comment: I don’t see any really good way to avoid brute force. The questions when is $10000a+100b+c$ divisible by $100a+10b+c.$

Comment: One thing you have is if the larger number is odd so is c.

Comment: I'm looking for the best way to minimize the number of cases to test. Right now there are $9x8x7=504$ cases. Maybe we can bring that down to less than 50 which is realistic to check by hand?

Comment: Your last statement is also true for mod $3$ and mod $11$.

Comment: They are also congruent mod 10

Comment: @RoddyMacPhee Oh, now *that* could be actually helpful! And I think that has to be accurate by CRT, right?  In fact, doesn't it then follow that A0B0 and AB are equivalent mod $99$ ?

Comment: if we demand $a, c \neq 0$   there are just a few,  most of which come from $x^4 + x^2 y^2 + y^4 = (x^2 + xy + y^2) (x^2 - xy + y^2),$   but a few others. Without that restriction, there are fifty examples.

Comment: Oh wait... I think I was wrong about mod $11$. Darn. I looked at alternating zeroes and misthought. Instead they differ by $2b \pmod{11}$.

Comment: @WillJagy Yeah, OP asks for $a \ne b \ne c \ne 0$. Am I correcting assuming that $x = 10k$ in the factorization you give?

Comment: The only solutions are $1, 2, 6$ and $2, 8, 5$.

Comment: @EricSnyder right. Apparently $a,b,c$ are required distinct. So the 10101/111 = 91  is not allowed

Comment: @GeoffreyTrang Did you find that via brute force or through number-theoretic methods? I mean, programming-wise this should take a split second, but the point was to try to find values otherwise.

Comment: I found the solutions $1,2,6$ and $2,8,5$ by brute-force.

Comment: Perhaps a way to approach this is to ask what the quotient $q= \frac{a0b0c}{abc}$ could be.  It is rather more constrained than $abc$ itself:  It cannot be as large as 100, and, unless $c=5$,  its units digit must be $1$ or $6$.   Probably the $q(100a+x) = 10000a+y$ condition, where $y<1000$, constrains the tens digit of $q$ also.

Comment: @MJD Indeed the quotient is minimized at $a=1,b=9,c=9$ so $q$ is between $55$ and $100$.